# Tranferring from STP to FCP

Tags: post-production, conform, final-cut-pro

I have an FCP file whose audio I exported to STP in order to apply filters, change levels, etc. Once finished in STP, I wanted to re-export my edited audio clips back into FCP, to update my FCP sequence to reflect my edits from STP. However, I can't figure out how to conform FCP to an updated STP sequence. I understand how to conform STP with an updated FCP file, but can it work in reverse, updating Final Cut with edited clips from Soundtrack Pro?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's meant to work that way. The edits won't show up unless you export them out as an AAF and re-import them into FCP. If you can live without the edits, you can send you tracks, buses, and submixes back to FCP via the export function. Take note that the clips on each tracks will be mixdown so you won't see your edit points in between the start and end of the clips.